# javascript: created img onclick not works

Tags: javascript, onclick

Seems weird problem, but perhaps I'm just a noob. 
Dinamically created IMG, every element (src,id,border,title) ok, except onclick: comment in code.

```
    var img = document.createElement('IMG');
    var href = result;
    var idx = result.lastIndexOf("/");
    img.src = result.substr(0,idx+1) + 'thumbs/' + result.substr(idx+1);
    img.border = 0;
    img.id = "qq1";
/* the following checked one by one
    img.onclick = 'alert("Kakukk")' ;           //does nothing - at stop (error: toSource) img=>onclick null
    img.onclick = alert("Kakukk") ;             // prints "Kakukk" here
    img.onclick = function(){alert("Kakukk");}; //does nothing;  at stop img=>onclick missing on debug => local variables !! 
    var myf = 'alert("Kakukk")';
    img.onclick=myf;                            //does nothing - at stop img=>onclick null
    img.onclick='function(){alert("Kakukk");}'; //does nothing - at stop img=>onclick null
*/
    img.addEventListener('click', function() {alert("Kakukk"); }, false);  //does nothing - at stop img=>onclick null
    img.title = 'Marci';

    alert("myObject4 is " + img.toSource());   // stop IE on error, check variables on debug screen
```

What the hell I missed?

Result: Most of code working well, onclick fine, I was just turning round and round around IE debug, what shows wrong value. Not javascript problem. Thx 4 all. *Never belive n00bs ;)*

Comment: are you familiar with jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean // prints "Kakukk" here?

Comment: "Kakukk" printed when script reached this point

Comment: Then that's what you want, isn't it? So you just do img.onclick = function(){yourstuffgoeshere};

Comment: nope, i wanna see "Kakukk" when I click on image :)

Answer (score 0):

Native emacScript should be written addEvenListener and for iE attachtEvent

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the img to the document:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Working example here:
http://jsbin.com/limomulora/1/edit

(PS: You should really be using addEventListener anyway)

Comment: thx, nice - only problem, a later process will it add to the right place. I thought I can add onclick just like id or title .. . Need more learning!? :)

Comment: hmm, i just changed the sequence on your example by moving "document.body.appendChild(img);" to the end - and still working, so seems my code sequence is right;  need me some more test on original problem...

Comment: Yes, that is what the example does: `img.onclick = function() {alert('Hello');};`

The example is working, right?

Comment: Now I'm a bit closer to the problem: 1st at all the IE debug not really correct. 
The others: the main module's original goal is generating html. After a bit deeper check in module i saw it generates the code by using outerHTML on passed object (img). Seems outerHTML does not contain the event things (like onclick). As I told, I'm noob, so need searching-seeking-looking for solution... 
Thank you very much, your code led me the - perhaps - right way :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the Image in DOM. Use jQuery's Append or before or after method to add your IMG element on DOM.
e.g.

```
$('#demoDiv').append(img);  // appends img after div with id demoDiv
```

Comment: this is just a little "hack" in a bigger module ( old SPAW editor ) so - if not need - don't really want make big changes